# ggplot2 facets set plot colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Not sure if title appropriately explains my problem: Using facet wraps, I have one plot which is a summary of the other plots, this results in that plot having much higher values on the variable which I plot colors by. All other plots thus only show (mostly) one color: [Example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPnpC.png).

I wish the colorization to rather depend on the non-summary graphs, whereas I care less if the summary graph ends up only displaying mostly one color because of consisting of high values (lower values should still show appropriate colors though). Thankful for any help.

Example code:

```
library(gdata)
library(viridis)
library(ggplot2)
summary <- data.frame(x = 1:15, y = runif(15), z = runif(15, min = 15, max = 200))
dat2 <- data.frame(x = 1:15, y = runif(15), z = runif(15, min = 0, max = 30))
dat3 <- data.frame(x = 1:15, y = runif(15), z = runif(15, min = 0, max = 30))
dat4 <- data.frame(x = 1:15, y = runif(15), z = runif(15, min = 0, max = 30))
dat <- combine(summary, dat2, dat3, dat4)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point(aes(color = z)) +
scale_color_viridis(option = "magma") +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey93"),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"))`

p1 <- p +  facet_wrap(~source)
```

Comment: Is it ok if you just set the scores for `z` for those `summary` rows to 0? If so, run this line before you run the `ggplot()` code: `dat <- mutate(dat, z = if_else(source == "summary", 0, z))`

Comment: Unfortunately not, since these values still are interesting information, and while I expect most to be quite high, some could be lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
summary <- data.frame(x = 1:15, y = runif(15), z = runif(15, min = 15, max = 200))
dat2 <- data.frame(x = 1:15, y = runif(15), z = runif(15, min = 0, max = 30))
dat3 <- data.frame(x = 1:15, y = runif(15), z = runif(15, min = 0, max = 30))
dat4 <- data.frame(x = 1:15, y = runif(15), z = runif(15, min = 0, max = 30))
dat <- combine(summary, dat2, dat3, dat4)
dat_ <- subset(dat, source != "summary")

cut_off <- 70 # adjust here where you want the cut-off of z values to be.
summary2 <- subset(dat, source == "summary" & z < cut_off) 

p <- ggplot(dat_, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
 geom_point(aes(color = z)) +
 geom_point(data = summary2, aes(col = z)) +
 scale_color_viridis(option = "magma") +
 theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey93"),
       strip.background = element_blank(),
       panel.grid = element_blank(),
       panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"))

p1 <- p +  facet_wrap(~source)

summary3 <- subset(dat, source == "summary" & z >= cut_off)
p1 + geom_point(data = summary3, col = "red") # adjust the color aesthetic of the highest summary graph points here.
```

So what you'll see is, summary data with a z value greater than or equal to 70 colored "red" in the summary graph, so they contrast with the viridis magma scale. (Experiment with "white", it contrasts nicely, too). All summary data observations with a z values less than 70 will follow the same color scale as the other three graphs, in the summary graph. Lower the `cut_off` variable (that is currently set to 70) to get more color in the dat2, dat3, and dat4 graphs.

This is the exact answer you've been looking for.

Comment: Didn't know you could add graphs on top of a facet wrap like this, and appreciate learning it. However, I still wish for any potentially lower values in the summary graph to show the appropriate scale colors, so this doesn't quite solve my problem.

Comment: I made edits to my original answer. Tell me if this works, and if it does, what adjustments you'd need, if any.

Comment: Doesn't quite work either. I need a particular color to represent the same value across graphs for the sake of comparability, e.g. a z = 30 in one graph should have the same color as a z = 30 in all other graphs. I was originally using gridextra but went over to facet wrapping for this reason. I appreciate the attempts!

Comment: Try the latest edit—there's more color in the dat2, dat3, and dat4 graphs. And all the highest values from the summary data are "red" in the summary graph, so they contrast with the viridis magma scale. Lower the `cut_off` variable to get more color in the dat2, dat3, and dat4 graphs.

Comment: Figured out a slightly more condensed way to do what you did, which is to just set limits to `scale_color_viridis`, and then set the NA values to desired color with `na.value = `. Thanks for the help!